# Probability of finding single particle state in QM and QFT

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, probability, quantum-optics

I was reading "Quantum Optics" by Walls and Milburn, and in chapter 10.1 describing about atom-radiation interaction, it says normal QM equation for single electron in an atom (here $\psi_j(x)$ is an energy eigenstates),

$$\psi(x)=\sum_j a_j \psi_j (x)  $$

could be quantized to a field operator,
$$\hat{\psi}^\dagger (x)=\sum _j \hat{a_j} ^\dagger \psi^*_j (x) $$
Here $\hat{a_j}^\dagger$ is a creation operator for Fock state.

For normal QM equation, probability for energy state $\psi _j (x)$ being selected is $|a_j|^2$, by Born rule, and probability that this state measured to have specific position $x$ is $|\psi_j (x)|^2$. Therefore probability that $\psi(x)$ is being measured to have energy state $j$ and position $x$ should be $|a_j|^2|\psi_j(x)|^2$.

Now for the case of QFT, field operator $\hat{\psi}^\dagger(x)$ acts on vacuum state $\left|0\right>$, then 
$$\hat{\psi} ^\dagger (x) \left|0\right>= \sum _j  \psi^*_j (x) \hat{a_j} ^\dagger \left|0\right> = \sum _j  \psi^*_j (x) \left|1_j \right>$$

Now I believe $\left|1_j \right>$ is a state having energy same as QM state $\psi_j(x)$ and having position exactly $x$. Since we are talking about single electron, I believe $\left|1_j \right>$ is same as $\psi_j(x)$ with fixed position $x$. But instead of probability we calculated above, $\left|1_j \right>$ state has probability of only $|\psi_j(x)|^2$.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT:** After some search, and thanks to the answer by Charles Francis, I have found the solution to my confusion.

The whole confusion was from the notation. Here, $\psi(x)$ is a wavefunction of single electron state, and I thought $\hat{\psi} ^\dagger (x)$ is an operator generating this wavefunction $\psi(x)$ due to the resemblance of the notation, which is **incorrect!** Actually textbook has unrigorous approach to quantizing process.

From [this lecture note](http://physics.gu.se/~tfkhj/OsloSecondQuant.pdf) or any other reference about second qunatization one could find basis transformation of creation and annihilation operator, given as 
$$\hat{a}^\dagger _{\tilde{\alpha}} = \sum_\alpha \left< \alpha | \tilde{\alpha}  \right> \hat{a}^\dagger _\alpha $$
Here $\{ \left|\alpha\right> \}$ and $\{ \left|\tilde{\alpha}\right> \}$ is some basis of Hilbert space. Putting basis $\{ \left|x\right> \}$ instead of $\{ \left|\tilde{\alpha}\right> \}$ gives
$$\hat{a}^\dagger _{x} = \sum_\alpha \left< \alpha | x  \right> \hat{a}^\dagger _\alpha= \sum_\alpha \psi_\alpha^* (x) \hat{a}^\dagger_\alpha  $$
One can now notice that **field operator $\hat{\psi} ^\dagger (x)$ was actually an operator generating one particle at position $x$**. Therefore $\hat{\psi} ^\dagger (x) \left|0\right>=\left|x\right>$, not $\left|\psi\right>$.

And as Charles Francis mentioned, creation operator for $\left|\psi\right>$ analogous to the equation $\psi(x)=\sum_j a_j \psi_j (x)  $, needs to be defined independent to the definition of $\hat{\psi} ^\dagger (x)$, and that will be
$$\hat{\psi} \equiv \sum_j a_j \hat{a_j}^\dagger$$
Of course, $a_j$ is just an probability coefficient, and $\hat{a_j}^\dagger$ is an creation operator for energy state $j$.

Comment: What does *"state has probability of only $\lvert \psi_j(x)\rvert^2$"* mean? Probability of *what*? Also, $\psi_j$ is now an operator, taking its absolute value does not make sense anymore.

Comment: The book says $\psi_j(x)$ is a complex 'function', while $\psi(x)$ is an operator, since it consists of not only $\psi_j(x)$ but also with $a_j$, which is an 'operator'. To make it unambiguous I will put hat on an operator.

Comment: This is a handwaving comment by an experimental physicist. I think  the fields are represented by the solution of the quantum mechanical equation of the particle under study without a potential, the plane wave solution. The number operator acting on the field gives 1 particle , i.e. its wavefunction which can be integrated , and the sum is like a partial wave analysis of the wavefunction that would have been calculated if the potential were known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to say I think the notation is horrible. I would not use it this way but it is clear that
$$ \left|1_j \right> = \hat{a_j} ^\dagger \left|0\right>  $$
and that this is not related to $\psi$. $\psi_j (x)$ are the coefficients of $\hat{\psi}  (x)$ in the energy basis.

One cannot think of $\psi_j (x)$ as referring to definite energy and position, because that is forbidden by the uncertainty principle. This can only be treated as a function of position at particular energy.

Part of the problem is that it is common in applied maths to be ambiguous about whether $\psi (x)$ means the function $\psi$ or whether it means the value of that function at the point $x$. Ket notation can be good for removing that ambiguity.

It may help to write your first equation
$$ \psi(x) = \langle x|\psi \rangle = \sum_j \langle x| 1_j \rangle \langle 1_j|\psi\rangle = \sum_j a_j(x)\psi_j. $$
I think this shows that the argument is incorrectly placed. The energy eigenstates have wave functions $a_j(x)$, and the $\psi_j$ are coefficients in the energy basis. It can be written
$$ \psi = |\psi \rangle = \sum_j | 1_j \rangle \langle 1_j|\psi\rangle = \sum_j a_j\psi_j. $$

when you quantise it, replacing $|1_j\rangle$ with the creation operator and ignoring $|0\rangle$  this becomes
$$ \hat\psi^\dagger  = \sum_j {\hat a_j}^\dagger\psi_j $$
and since $\psi$ is arbitrary, we can replace it with $\psi(x)$ so as to construct a field operator
$$ \hat\psi^\dagger(x)  = \sum_j {\hat a_j}^\dagger\psi_j(x) $$

Comment: So do you mean the whole confusion comes from the horrible notation of the book? If I am understanding your comment right, $\psi_j(x)$ in the QM equation (wave function of energy eigenstate) is different from $\psi_j(x)$ in QFT equation (which is function, but work as coefficient of energy basis). If I denote first one as $\psi_j(x)_{QM}$ and second one $\psi_j(x)_{QFT}$, then their relationship will be $\psi_j(x)_{QFT}=a_j \psi_j(x)_{QM}$. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes, the functions are not the same. I have filled in a bit, but tbh I think the method of second quantisation is always confusing. People are more concerned that they end up with formulae which work, rather than how they actually get the formulae.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, and some search by my own, I was able to get solution to this problem. I have edited my question to clarify my confusion once more and added the points you have made in your answer. As from the beginning, it was all notation problem.

Comment: Well done. Much better to have worked through your own solution. I was wondering about writing down $\hat{\psi} ^\dagger (x) \left|0\right>=\left|x\right>$, but I wasn't exactly sure of your application.

Comment: That line came from the chapter 4 of the lecture note I have linked, but if you think it has a problem, I would be pleased to hear your opinion.

Comment: No, I don't think it has a problem. Usually I would think it important, but I am used to using momentum states, not energy states, and I am not sure why the coefficients are $\psi_j(x) $ instead of $e^{ix.p}$, so I thought I would risk getting something wrong.